# I installed a new light fixture and it won't turn off!

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture, dimmer-switch

I removed a fan/light combo and replaced with a typical light fixture. The wires from the ceiling coming out are white, black and ground. The light fixture has a positive and a neg and a ground. I flipped the light switch and it won't turn off. I took apart the light switch and the light switch has a black wire, white, and red wire. I don't know what to do. I feel like I have tried all possible combinations.

Comment: Were the fan and light controlled together or separately? I have a hunch that the ground was illegally being used as a neutral, and the black and white were both hots. Please post a photo or clear description of the switch connections.

Comment: did It work before? Since you used positive and negative your knowledge of AC wiring is very limited. A photo of the wires in each box would be helpful including additional information were there 2 switches one for the light and 1 for the fan or just 1 switch with a switch on the fan controlling the light.

Comment: Don't just randomly connect wires!  Since the "switch" you are using was designed for that combo fan/light, it may well not match up to the vanilla light fixture.  Get help onsite from someone who knows electrical wiring -- don't risk hurting yourself.

Comment: I think you may be on to something @CarlWitthoft. That switch may be a custom unit that can only control the particular fan/light that was there before. .  Hopefully OP will post pictures of switch and wiring